# How to install libraries or packages in R for oracle?

Tags: r, linux, solaris

I'm using solaris to install Oracle's R.
The version of solaris de oracle is 5.11

I followed these steps:

1) Install R. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E83411_01/OREAD/installing-oracle-R-distribution-on-oracle-solaris.htm#OREAD139

2.) Install client packages: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E83411_01/OREAD/installing-the-ORE-packages.htm#OREAD349

3) Install support packages https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E83411_01/OREAD/installing-the-ORE-supporting-packages.htm#OREAD248

When I start R, from the console and I need to install these libraries
devtools, twiteR, write. I've tried it from the R console as from the solaris terminal for example:

```
R CMD INSTALL devtools.1.13.5.tar.gz.tar.gz
```

ouput:

> oracle@ATMBISOL:~/Escritorio/oreclient_install_dir/librerias$ R CMD INSTALL devtools_1.13.5.tar.gz Warning in strptime(xx, f <- "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS", tz = tz) :
>     unknown timezone 'nfo/Europe/Madrid'
>   * installing to library ‘/export/home/oracle/R/x86_64-pc-solaris2.10-library/3.3’
>   ERROR: dependencies ‘httr’, ‘memoise’, ‘digest’, ‘jsonlite’, ‘git2r’ are not available for package ‘devtools’
>   * removing ‘/export/home/oracle/R/x86_64-pc-solaris2.10-library/3.3/devtools’
>   oracle@ATMBISOL:~/Escritorio/oreclient_install_dir/librerias$

from R console

```
install.packages("devtools", dependencies=TRUE,repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')
```

output:

> Installing package into
>   ‘/export/home/oracle/R/x86_64-pc-solaris2.10-library/3.3’
>       (as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
>       Warning: unable to access index for repository http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib:
>         no fue posible abrir la URL 'http://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/PACKAGES'
>       Warning message:
>       package ‘devtools’ is not available (for Oracle Distribution of R version 3.3.0)

Does anyone know the reason?

Thank you.

Comment: I want to install the packages "devtools", "twitter", and "write.
Then with R connect to twitter developer and extract a few comments in the .csv file.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I don't think `devtools` is for Solaris. You'd have to create a virtual machine with another OS, like the Github link mentioned.

Comment: @Hack-R According to https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_devtools.html devtools works on Solaris.

Comment: Does the machine have internet access? If not you will have to download all packages including their dependencies manually.

Comment: As said by @RalfStubner download each dependency listed in your error (_httr_, _memoise_,..) and install them manually (**R CMD INSTALL** as you tried with devtools)

Comment: Yes, the solaris machine has internet access.
Making several attempts to install this error, for example:
1: In install.packages("devtools",dependiences = TRUE): installation of package 'backports' had non  zero exit status
The solution in ubuntu is sudo apt-get install curl libssl-dev libcurl4-openssl-dev libxml2-dv